# Android: Passing a non-primitive ArrayList type from one fragment to another in a bundle

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I currently have this Custom ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<PlaceDetails> place_list = new ArrayList<PlaceDetails>();
```

which will be populated during the onCreateView() portion.

I am unsure as of how do I pass this ArrayList in a bundle from this fragment class to another fragment class. Below is the snippet of my codes:

```
public void Map(View view){
    if(hasConnection() == true){
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // how should I be passing the ArrayList in this bundle?
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TOnlineMapViewFragment mapfrag = TOnlineMapViewFragment.newInstance(b);
        ft.replace(R.id.container, mapfrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
}
```

So I've created the bundle and I wanted to pass it to the next fragment with the newInstance() method. How should I do this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you really sure a bundle is really needed?

```
 TOnlineMapViewFragment mapfrag = TOnlineMapViewFragment.newInstance(b);
 mapfrag.setPlaceList(place_list)
```

Should be trivial to create `setPlaceList(ArrayList<PlaceDetails> place_list)` ...

Comment: Really? I've never seen people do that before... They usually do so in the bundle...

Comment: Wow ok seems like this might actually work... but are there any dangers in doing so? Otherwise why would people use Bundles instead? I asked this question because I've never seen examples that do it like you suggested

Comment: People use Bundle when they start a new Activity.. In your case, you are in the same Activity!

Comment: So fragments are all considered to be in the same activity?

Comment: So, is it working? That's what I use in some of my apps and that's working nicely.

Comment: It's not safe though.

Comment: Can you develop please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider implementing [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface in your classes. Then you would be able to store PlaceDetails in Bundle and pass it to setArguments() method.

I've found a tutorial: http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/
I haven't testes it but it looks good.

Comment: Thanks for this! Though I'm not sure if that solution would work though because it works on Intent and activities, while I'm working on fragments.